# Error when converting office files to pdf with documents4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, vbscript, converters, documents4j

I am trying to use documents4J to convert the office files and images to PDF, but am getting "*Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings*".

Here is my current code:

```
package documentsForJ;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File wordFile = new File("test.doc"), target = new File("test.pdf");

        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().baseFolder(new File("G:\\documentsForJ\\target"))
                .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        Future<Boolean> conversion = converter.convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(target).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                // .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                .schedule();

    }
}
```

I have bind on the following Jars:

- documents4j-api-1.0.2.jar documents4j-client-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-client-standalone-1.0.2-shaded.jar
- documents4j-local-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-server-standalone-1.0.2-shaded.jar
- documents4j-test-1.0.2.jar documents4j-transformer-api-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-transformer-msoffice-base-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-transformer-msoffice-excel-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-transformer-msoffice-test-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-util-standalone-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-util-transformer-process-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-util-ws-1.0.2.jar documents4j-server-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-transformer-1.0.2.jar documents4j-util-all-1.0.2.jar
- documents4j-util-conversion-1.0.2.jar

When I run the Application, I get the following Error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/G:/AdminPrgs/Code/Java/eclipse/workspaceTest/documentsForJ/lib/documents4j-client-standalone-1.0.2-shaded.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/G:/AdminPrgs/Code/Java/eclipse/workspaceTest/documentsForJ/lib/documents4j-server-standalone-1.0.2-shaded.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
16:28:49.030 [main] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Executing [cmd, /C, "C:\temp\excel_start1565707660.vbs"] in C:\temp.
16:28:49.038 [main] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Started java.lang.ProcessImpl@1bc6a36e
16:28:49.074 [WaitForProcess-java.lang.ProcessImpl@1bc6a36e] DEBUG o.zeroturnaround.exec.WaitForProcess - java.lang.ProcessImpl@1bc6a36e stopped with exit code 3
16:28:49.081 [main] INFO  c.d.c.msoffice.MicrosoftExcelBridge - From-Microsoft-Excel-Converter was started successfully
16:28:49.085 [main] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Executing [cmd, /C, "C:\temp\word_start2143216009.vbs"] in C:\temp.
16:28:49.086 [main] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Started java.lang.ProcessImpl@6fffcba5
16:28:49.121 [WaitForProcess-java.lang.ProcessImpl@6fffcba5] DEBUG o.zeroturnaround.exec.WaitForProcess - java.lang.ProcessImpl@6fffcba5 stopped with exit code 3
16:28:49.121 [main] INFO  c.d.c.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge - From-Microsoft-Word-Converter was started successfully
16:28:49.132 [main] INFO  com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter - The documents4j local converter has started successfully
fertig!
16:28:49.145 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.d.c.msoffice.MicrosoftExcelBridge - Requested conversion from AbrechnungKFZ-Kosten.xls (application/vnd.ms-excel) to AbrechnungKFZ-Kosten.pdf (application/pdf)
16:28:49.148 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Executing [cmd, /C, "C:\temp\excel_convert961528339.vbs G:\AdminPrgs\Code\Java\eclipse\workspaceTest\documentsForJ\AbrechnungKFZ-Kosten.xls G:\AdminPrgs\Code\Java\eclipse\workspaceTest\documentsForJ\AbrechnungKFZ-Kosten.pdf 999"] in C:\temp.
16:28:49.148 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Started java.lang.ProcessImpl@39bd6b04
16:28:49.188 [WaitForProcess-java.lang.ProcessImpl@39bd6b04] DEBUG o.zeroturnaround.exec.WaitForProcess - java.lang.ProcessImpl@39bd6b04 stopped with exit code -4
```

The generated VBS C:\temp\excel_start1565707660.vbs gives the following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezx55.png)

And that is the code of the generated vbs:

```
' See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243311%28v=office.12%29.aspx
Const WdExportFormatPDF = 17
Const MagicFormatPDF = 999

Dim arguments
Set arguments = WScript.Arguments

' Transforms a file using MS Excel into the given format.
Function ConvertFile( inputFile, outputFile, formatEnumeration )

  Dim fileSystemObject
  Dim excelApplication
  Dim excelDocument

  ' Get the running instance of MS Excel. If Excel is not running, exit the conversion.
  On Error Resume Next
  Set excelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  If Err <> 0 Then
    WScript.Quit -6
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Find the source file on the file system.
  Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  inputFile = fileSystemObject.GetAbsolutePathName(inputFile)

  
  ' Convert the source file only if it exists.
  If fileSystemObject.FileExists(inputFile) Then

    ' Attempt to open the source document.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelDocument = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(inputFile, , True, , , , , , , , , , , , 2)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        WScript.Quit -2
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Convert: See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221597.aspx
    On Error Resume Next
    If formatEnumeration = MagicFormatPDF Then
      excelDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, outputFile
    Else
      excelDocument.SaveAs outputFile, formatEnumeration
    End If

    ' Close the source document.
    excelDocument.Close False
    If Err <> 0 Then
        WScript.Quit -3
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Signal that the conversion was successful.
    WScript.Quit 2

  Else

    ' Files does not exist, could not convert
    WScript.Quit -4

  End If

End Function

' Execute the script.
Call ConvertFile( arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), arguments.Unnamed.Item(1), CInt(arguments.Unnamed.Item(2)) )
```

Why is this error happening, and how can the problem be fixed?

Comment: It seems like you might be using special characters somewhere in a file. VBS is complaining that you have less then three arguments provided in your script. Currentlty, there is a bug where spaces in any file name are not escaped properly and fail the conversion. Something similar seems to be the problem in your case.

Comment: Give proper path to test.doc, seems like the script isn't able to find them. Try putting it in a folder without spaces and refer to it like `File wordFile = new File("C:\\test\\test.doc");` A folder with spaces also should work, but try this one out first.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely resolved in the newly released documents4j version 1.0.3 which adds proper escaping to the conversion script arguments. Previously, no arguments were escaped what can cause confusion when VBScript processes the script arguments as observed by you.